# Doctrine 2 how to Order By amount of many to many relation?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, dql

How would you OrderBy the amount of many to many relation with Doctrine2.
I'm wondering how that is possible.

If not, what do you suggest ? I would like to avoid doing a huge foreach with multiple requests.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb->select( 'p', 'e', 'un', 'i', 'c' )
        ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
        ->leftJoin( 'e.place', 'p' )
        ->leftJoin( 'e.userNotified', 'un' )
        ->leftJoin( 'e.invitations', 'i', 'WITH', 'i.friend = :user' )
        ->innerJoin( 'e.categories', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.parent = :cat' )
        ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC')
        ->setFirstResult( $offset )
        ->setMaxResults( $limit );
```

And I would like to orderBy e.usersNotified. (Many to Many relation).

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can ORDER BY your many to many entities by using anotations like this :

```
 /**
 * ...
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"some_attribute" = "ASC", "another_attribute" = "ASC"})
 */

 private $yourAttribute;
```

So you have just to make the query on your attribute and they are already ordered the way you want ;)

Comment: Thanks Chamlee.
So hang on, I need to do that in my entities annotations ?
I can't find a reference for that.

Comment: Yes you had to do this in your entities annotations.
I invite you to take a look at the the official doctrine doc :
[Doctrine DOC](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-orderby)

Comment: Thank you, I did re-read it, but I can't find anywhere where they say I can sort it by `count the amount of relations`. It's more like sorting by age or whatever ..

Comment: This will only order those related entities in the given order, it won't return you the original entities ordered by which entity has the most related entities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually use the builder (I prefer to write out the DQL), but I believe this should work (I've got a similar thing to work in DQL).

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select( 'p', 'e', 'un', 'i', 'c', 'COUNT(e) AS HIDDEN counter' )
    ->from( 'Entity\Event',  'e' )
    ->leftJoin( 'e.place', 'p' )
    ->leftJoin( 'e.userNotified', 'un' )
    ->leftJoin( 'e.invitations', 'i', 'WITH', 'i.friend = :user' )
    ->innerJoin( 'e.categories', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.parent = :cat' )
    ->orderBy('e.dateStart', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('counter ASC')
    ->setFirstResult( $offset )
    ->setMaxResults( $limit );
```